# Como executar um .jar usando o java jdbc em outra maquina

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, jar

Sou iniciante na área de java, eu fiz um aplicação usando o banco de dados nativo do netbeans.
Gero o arquivo `jar`, e na máquina que eu fiz a aplicação o `jar`  executa normalmente, mais quando coloco esse jar em outra maquina ele apenas abre, mais quando chega na parte que faz a conexão no banco (exemplo quando clico no botão cadastrar, na cadastrar, e nem lista) ele simplesmente não abre.

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para executar em outra máquina, tipo ele foi feito no windows 10, e quero executar no windows 7.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Para que a comunidade possa te ajudar, é importante que se explique detalhadamente o seu problema. Seria interessante anexar um Log de erro para facilitar!

Sugiro que leia os artigos: [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e [como realizar uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Como você está fazendo a conexão e como gera o banco no app? Adicione o código ai, o netbeans cria uma conexao apenas local pro seu computador, a uri será invalida em outro.

Comment: public class Dao {
  //  private static List<Usuario> banco = new  LinkedList<Usuario>();
    EntityManagerFactory emf= Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Aplica__oPU");
    EntityManager em =emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction etx = em.getTransaction();

Comment: public void salve(Object o){
     
        etx.begin();
        em.merge(o);
        etx.commit();
     
  }
  public void remover(Object o){
     etx.begin();
     em.remove(o);   
   etx.commit();
  }
  public List listar(Class o){
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT o FROM "+o.getSimpleName()+" o");
        return q.getResultList();
    }

Comment: não sei se deu para entender, mais esse ai é o código que uso para fazer a conexão com o banco, e uso uma classe percistencia.xml

Comment: @EndersonCesar, você poderia atualizar a sua pergunta com os parâmetros de conexão que você usa? Muito provavelmente você está conectando em localhost (pois está desenvolvendo na sua máquina). Quando você distribui sua aplicação, você precisa mudar localhost para o IP (ou DNS) da máquina aonde está o banco de dados.

Comment: olá eu estou usando o caminho, jdbc://debylocalhost:1127/sample[app em APP], esse é o caminho do banco em minha maquina, mais estou tentando rodar o jar em apena uma maquina, tenho qe mudar esse caminho?

Answer (score -1):

No cenário que você está relatando, a máquina que você deseja executar o seu `jar` deverá estar na mesma rede que a máquina que contém o banco de dados.

Então, no local que você utilizou o `localhost` na sua configuração de conexão, será passado o IP da máquina que contém a base de dados.

Um exemplo:

- Máquina 1 (base de dados): IP: 10.3.1.100
- Máquina 2 (jar): IP: 10.3.1.102

Para que a máquina 2 possa se comunicar com a máquina 1, no seu `persistence.xml`, será necessário configurar a `property` responsável pela url da seguinte forma:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:meu_sgbd://ip_maquina_1/minha_base_de_dados" />
```

Obs: Não esqueça de informar a porta utilizada pelo SGBD.